# timing within a loop postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, loops, timing

I created a function in postgres and it has a query inside a loop which iterates for n times. I want to know the execution time for each iteration. (given here is a similar function)

'\timing' will give the function call execution time but not exactly the loop iteration time.

```
create function somefunction()
return something
---
Declare
--
--
BEGIN
for somevalue in something
loop 
insert into table_name
select name,id from sales where name = "John"; --want to know the execution time of this statement
end loop;
return 
END
$$ language plpgsql volatile;
```

I also tried  placing EXPLAIN ANALYZE before the insert statement in the loop (as below)

```
loop
EXPLAIN ANALYZE insert into table_name
select name,id from sales where name = "John";
end loop;
```

Giving this error - ERROR:  query has no destination for result data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to store the results of the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to a record or a character varying variable so that you use that variable for viewing the result later.

Something like this:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE insert into table_name 
    select name,id from sales where name = "John" INTO result;
```

Then you can now use that variable to see the execution time by either using `RAISE NOTICE` or inserting it to a new table or whatever you like